# Adding security to android app communicating with online MYSQL database

Tags: android, mysql

i am new to androd development. I am developing an android app which.communicates with remote online MYSQL database. But i want to know what are the ways in which someone can hack my online data base with my android app and also how to protect my app from those?

Comment: A fairly standard design would be to create a REST webservice that interacts with your database, and have your android app interact with that. That way, your database isn't directly exposed to the internet, and your app users will only be able to interact with it in predefined ways, with very tight control over which parameters they can modify. If your android app interacts directly with the database, it will likely be straightforward to pull credentials out of the app, giving everyone the same level of access to your MySQL database that your app has.